# Mutate Column Using Text Matching

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, dplyr

I have a character vector in a data frame with >500 values - about 50 of them are multiple iterations of the same thing (ie "Tulip" and "Small Tulip" and "Tulip "Tulip - Fresh Cut" and then similarly "Rose" "Mini Rose" "Climbing Rose."

I want to convert this to another column, where I specify that each of these becomes "Tulip" or "Rose" or maintains its prior value if it does not match either.

For example,

1. Mini Rose
2. Peonie
3. Tulip
4. Red Rose
5. Small Tulip
6. Tulip - Fresh Picked
7. Violet
8. Daffodil
9. Pink Tulips
10. Roses

Should become... 
1. Rose
2. Peonie 
3. Tulip
4. Rose
5. Tulip 
6. Tulip
7. Violet
8. Daffodil 
9. Tulips
10. Rose

I have tried this a ton of ways using mutate and lapply and grep and various iterations without success. Any advice? It seems like something basic to do in R but I have struggled to find a solution

Comment: Please create a reproducible example by using `dput` to export your table as copiable text and including that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple case of string/regex matching and assigning a new (or old variable) with `if_else` or `dplyr::case_when`. Here's one of the may ways you can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

flower_data = tibble(flower = c("Type of Rose", "Type of Tulip", "Other Flower")) 
flower_data %>%
  mutate(new_flower = case_when(
    stringi::stri_detect_regex(flower, "[Rr]ose") ~ "Rose",
    stringi::stri_detect_regex(flower, "[Tt]ulip") ~ "Tulip",
    TRUE ~ flower
  ))
```

I like `stringi`'s implementation because I've found it much faster than `stringr::str_detect` and `case_when` over nested `if_else` statements because of readability.